# Using dataCache property in view control in XPages

Tags: xpages

In the the data source of a view control there is a property of `dataCache` with options of Full, ID and NoData. From [some sources](http://wpc.0b0c.edgecastcdn.net/000B0C/LUG/VUG/2011/AdminDevSessions/MainSessions/Admin2011_Elgort_Xpagesperformance.pdf) I gather that:

Full - The entire view is persisted

ID - Minimal scalar data ID and position. Access to column values during a POST are not available

None - Enough said – the entire view needs to be reconstructed

But exactly how does this property effect performance of the XPage? Which are the methods/functionality I can use in each of these options? What is the suitability of each option?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested, but I would presume the following are true. The more you persist in memory, the quicker it is to restore for expand/collapse etc. However, the more users and the bigger the view (number of columns rather than number of documents, because not all documents will get cached), the more risk of out of memory issues. Access to column values means you may have problems using getColumnValues() in SSJS from the view.

XPages is pretty quick, so unless you have specific performance issues, the default should be sufficient.